# nlog event context custom variables log error

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a simple setup with Nlog, its working fine when just passing through normal parameters like the message, but when i pass a LogEventInfo object like this:

```
//inside a class
private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogs");

//in a method
LogEventInfo logEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, "LogName", "some message");
logEvent.Properties.Add("httpMethod", "GET");
_logger.Warn(logEvent);
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.]
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
System.Collections.Generic.Enumerator.MoveNext() +10900893
NLog.Targets.Target.MergeEventProperties(LogEventInfo logEvent) +312
NLog.Targets.Target.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent) +74

[NLogRuntimeException: Exception occurred in NLog]
NLog.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Write>b__0(Exception ex) +150
NLog.Internal.SingleCallContinuation.Function(Exception exception) +153
NLog.Targets.Target.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent) +189
NLog.Targets.Target.WriteAsyncLogEvent(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent) +364
NLog.LoggerImpl.WriteToTargetWithFilterChain(TargetWithFilterChain targetListHead, LogEventInfo logEvent, AsyncContinuation onException) +341
NLog.LoggerImpl.Write(Type loggerType, TargetWithFilterChain targets, LogEventInfo logEvent, LogFactory factory) +351
NLog.Logger.WriteToTargets(LogLevel level, IFormatProvider formatProvider, T value) +136
NLog.Logger.Warn(T value) +106
proj.Infrastructure.Logging.LogResponse(String message, IOwinContext context, String flow, String action) in c:\Sites\proj\Infrastructure\Logging.cs:45
proj.<Validate>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Sites\proj\myclass.cs:40
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__1e.MoveNext() +1049
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +1735
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +664
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +22
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +33
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +150
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +42
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +415
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

This is the nlog configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" 
       internalLogLevel="Trace"
       throwExceptions="true">
   <targets>
     <target xsi:type="File" name="textFile"
          fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}/file.txt" layout="${message} ${event-context:item=httpMethod}"/>
   </targets>
   <rules>
     <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="textFile" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

I have had a search, and cant find anything related. The nlog version i am using is: 3.1.0.0

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does this error occur *every* time you try to run your code and `_logger.Warn(logEvent);` is called?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Yeh thats right.

Comment: Possible spelling mistake?  Your layout has this: `${event-context:item=httpmMethod}`.  Looks like you have an extra `m`.

Comment: @BrendanGreen That was just a typo when formatting the code here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should use `void Log(LogEventInfo logEvent)` method.

```
_logger.Log(logEvent);
```

Source: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventContext-Layout-Renderer

But if you want know why this happen, you can follow by link:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/commit/02e7eff1c5606ea4a4aa4dffc3114adf82791bd6

Comment: that pointed me in the right direction, seems strange that you cannot call _logger.Warn / Info etc and have to explicitly use void Log, i would think the former methods would take preference in terms of LogLevel